# Como activar una acción cuando hago clic o le doy enfoque a un QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit

Hola estoy construyendo un CRUD y quiero que se cargue un calendario cuando doy clic en una caja de texto que almacenará la fecha de nacimiento. Estuve revisando la documentación y vi que en señales hay algo . Sólo pude activar el evento o señal cuando presiono la tecla ENTER, yo lo que necesito es que se active cuando le doy clic a la caja de texto o escribo algo en ella. El objeto de la clase QLineEdit se llama txtFna le comparto la instrucción que implemento y que me funciona mas o menos por no decir que regular

```
self.txtFna.returnPressed.connect(self.llamocalendario)
```

y esta es función que llama al calendario que aun no implemento, esto lo podría realizar de forma sencilla usando un botón pero quiero hacerlo lo mas simple posible sin recargar tanto el formulario por eso deseo que se active cuando doy clic en la caja de texto, muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudar

```
def llamocalendario(self):
        print("esta acción me llama al calendario")
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece más simple usar directamente el calendario, si es lo que al fin y al cabo es lo que vas a llamar, o sea:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QDateTimeEdit
import sys

class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(300,400)
        cal = QDateTimeEdit(self) 
        cal.setCalendarPopup(True)
        cal.setDisplayFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

definimos directamente el calendario

```
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
Form_principal = Ventana()
Form_principal.show()
app.exec_()
```

Es por lo menos lo que entendí que buscas.

Comment: si efectivamente tienes razón es mas sencillo , pero yo tengo que manipular datos, por ejemplo concatenarlos con consultas SQL, a veces tengo que borrar los campos para evitar errores y con el objeto de la clase QDateEdit se me hace muy difícil, en estos momentos logré pasar los datos de este control a un Qlabel pero me muestra la información con otro formato

Comment: por ejemplo, al colocar la fecha de hoy (22-02-2022) con un objeto QDateEdit y pasarlo a un QLabel efectivamente me lo hace pero me imprime toda esta información PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0)

Comment: Podés obtener un objeto datetime "normal" aplicando el método `.toPyDateTime()` al objeto obtenido.